# python2.7 define the content of txt file

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, undefined

```
2330,0.5,13:30:08,121.5,106.5,114.5,115,113.5,114.5,37464,4243,114,1977,113.5,3710,113,5019,112.5,2943,112,1966,114.5,2305,115,4517,115.5,2459,116,2376,116.5,2186,0,1,24,1000,25928305829,name,22,33,44
```

This is the text file's content.
I set the file name in `fileLine`.
It is one line and split by comma.

```
number,rangep,timep,maxp,minp,openp,highp,lowp,closep,volume,curvolume,openprice,
openbvolume,bp1,bv1,bp2,bv2,bp3,bv3,bp4,bv4,bp5,bv5,sp1,sv1,sp2,sv2,sp3,sv3,sp4,sv4
sp5,sv5,un1,un2,un3,un4,un5,namep,un6,un7,un8 = np.loadtxt(fileLine,delimiter=',',umpack=True)
```

When I run this it shows all my variables are not defined. How can I set the content to variable, then I can plot the plot.

Comment: Did you split that series of variables over more than one line in your source code too? That won't work, Python will see the first two lines  as tuples, not as part of the assignment.

Comment: Just curious... Is that `umpack=True`? Is that a typo or a keyword?

Comment: @mogambo: it is a typo, but even when corrected is not what the OP should be using.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot split the assignment targets over multiple lines without telling Python explicitly that you are doing so. You could use parenthesis:

```
(number,rangep,timep,maxp,minp,openp,highp,lowp,closep,volume,curvolume,openprice,
 openbvolume,bp1,bv1,bp2,bv2,bp3,bv3,bp4,bv4,bp5,bv5,sp1,sv1,sp2,sv2,sp3,sv3,sp4,
 sv4,sp5,sv5,un1,un2,un3,un4,un5,namep,un6,un7,un8) = np.loadtxt(fileLine, delimiter=',')
```

However, I'd not try and assign this many variables from one line, it is rather unwieldy and unreadable.

You do *not* need to use `unpack=True` here, you are only loading one line, and you don't need to transpose multiple lines into columns here. In fact, using `numpy.loadtext()` could well be overkill here as you are unpacking the produced `array()` object into separate values again.

Given your data line, `numpy.txt` is the *wrong tool*; it expects all values to be of the same type (`float` by default) and your data line contains a *mix* of types.

You should avoid `numpy.loadtext()` altogether here; you could use:

```
with open(fileLine) as f:
    row = f.readline().split(',')
```

and index into that with `row[0]`, etc.

In this case, you could use the [`collections.namedtuple()` factory](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to produce a tuple for such a line, allowing you to address individual values by name still, while at the same time avoiding such a monster assignment line:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Values = namedtuple('Values',
    'number,rangep,timep,maxp,minp,openp,highp,lowp,closep,volume,curvolume,'
    'openprice,openbvolume,bp1,bv1,bp2,bv2,bp3,bv3,bp4,bv4,bp5,bv5,sp1,sv1,sp2,sv2,sp3,'
    'sv3,sp4,sv4,sp5,sv5,un1,un2,un3,un4,un5,namep,un6,un7,un8')

with open(fileLine) as f:
    values = Values(*f.readline().split(','))
```

Now you can address these as `values.number` and `values.curvolume`, etc.

You'll have to convert any values manually though.

Answer (score 1):

Since its a simple file, you can use `DictReader` from the `csv` module to get a more manageable data structure:

```
import csv

fields = ['number','rangep','timep','maxp','minp','openp','highp','lowp','closep','volume','curvolume','openprice','openbvolume','bp1','bv1','bp2','bv2','bp3','bv3','bp4','bv4','bp5','bv5','sp1','sv1','sp2','sv2','sp3','sv3','sp4','sv4','sp5','sv5','un1','un2','un3','un4','un5','namep','un6','un7','un8']

with open('somefile.txt') as f:
   reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=fields)
   rows = list(reader)

for row in rows:
    print(row['number']) # and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open(filename, 'r')
line = f.readline()
alist = line.split(',')
f.close()
```

And then you can just handle the data in the alist. For example: number as alist[0].